# Sync zip file with folder?

Tags: linux, shell, zip, synchronization

I know specifying a zip file in the command add the files to the zip file itself, but how can I really sync a folder having already a zip file so that it does add new files, replace modified files and delete absent files in the folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command-line "zip" tool has the -FS (or --filesync) flag that does exactly this (updates existing, adds new, deletes removed).

See http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html.

Comment: If anyone wants to see its explanation, it's available in the extended help, `zip -h2`.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line "zip" command has options for --freshen (update existing files only), --update (update and add files), and --delete to remove, but I couldn't find a way to combine them all into one command.

Since the zip file probably needs to be completely rewritten during processing anyways, why not just delete the old zip file and create a new one from scratch?

Comment: Since the files are synced through google drive, I have to avoid deleting the files, because then they are moved to trash in the drive account, and I have no way to automatically empty the trash, so I have to update the zip file so that the sync revise the file and does not move the files to trash.

Comment: OK, what if you first truncate the file:  echo -n > file.zip; and then run the zip command? Haven't tested how zip behaves when the target file is a 0 byte file, though. Alternatively, create the zip file in /tmp and move it over the existing one?